# What's the wrong with StringBuilder in code

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

```java
class Solution {
    public String mergeAlternately(String word1, String word2) {
        int length = word1.length() + word2.length();
        StringBuilder ans = new StringBuilder(length);
        int left = 0, right = 0, current = 0;
        System.out.println(ans.length());
        while(current < ans.length()) {
            System.out.println("called");
            if(left >= word1.length()) {
                ans.append(word2.charAt(right));
                right++;
            }
            else if(right >= word2.length()) {
                ans.append(word2.charAt(left));
                left++;
            }
            else if(current % 2 == 0) {
                ans.append(word1.charAt(left));
                left++;
            }
            else {
                ans.append(word2.charAt(right));
                right++;
            }
            current++;
        }
        return ans.toString();
    }
}
```

The problem is=> given two strings `word1` and `word2`. Merge the strings by adding letters in alternating order, starting with word1. If a string is longer than the other, append the additional letters onto the end of the merged string.

I have tried:

Input: `word1 = "abc", word2 = "pqr"`

Expected Output: `"apbqcr"`

my Output: `""`

Comment: `current < ans.length()` is always false because `ans` is empty.

Comment: i dont think ans is empty because he has initialized it with a length value

Comment: @RituparnaWarwatkar The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#%3Cinit%3E(int)) says the `StringBuilder` is empty: *Constructs a string builder with no characters in it and an initial capacity specified by the capacity argument.*

Comment: @RituparnaWarwatkar, that initializes its capacity.  Its length is still zero.

Comment: `current < length` is the approach here, especially since you instantiated `int length = word1.length() + word2.length();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Initial capacity versus length

Your code:

```
StringBuilder ans = new StringBuilder(length);
```

Defines an *initial capacity* for the string bulder, but does not fill it with any text. See the Javadoc:

> Constructs a string builder with no characters in it and an initial capacity specified by the capacity argument.

In other words, `new StringBuilder( 42 ).length()` returns `0` zero.

So your test `while(current < ans.length())` never returns `true`. Your `current` variable is never less than zero, never negative.

## `char` is legacy

The `char` type has been essentially broken since Java 2, legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, a `char` cannot represent most characters.

To work with individual characters, learn to use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integers.

Search Stack Overflow to learn more as this has been covered many times already.